# Rails showing images even though nginx misconfigured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app. I'm using the Carrierwave gem to allow image uploads to `public/system/...`.

In reviewing production app for performance tweaks, I realized that I misconfigured nginx, and that it's only serving static files from `/assets` instead of `/assets` *and* `/system`.

What I have:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

What I (think I) should have:

```
location ~ ^/(assets|system)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

However, `config.public_file_server.enabled = false` is set in `production.rb`.

So now i'm confused-- how is Rails serving these images? I'm assuming I have a (grossly) incomplete understanding of how the asset pipeline *actually* works?

**Update: nginx config**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/sockets/mydomain.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  root       /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log  /home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ~ ^/(assets|system)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location ~ ^/(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz)/ {
    root /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 50M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  # ssl certificate info...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help posting the whole nginx configuration for this application. Rails will respect public_file_server when served by passenger, puma etc. However, it can be easily overriden with nginx.
The common nginx config line

```
root /home/rails/testapp/public;
```

basically tells nginx to serve /public "as it is" and makes public_file_server irrelevant.
(perhaps).

Comment: So you are saying that the presence of the `root ...` declaration makes the `location ~ ^/assets/ {` statement superfluous-- setting `root` to the app `/public` directory will cause nginx to serve all static files in public anyways? If, for some reason, I did want nginx to only serve from the "assets" subdir of public, I would leave out the root declaration altogether?